# Difficulty in Framing query for successful login in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am having difficulty in framing the query for composing multiple conditions.

Here is my code

```
public boolean isuserloggedin()
{
    boolean flag = false;

    if((!driver.findElements(By.id("Cancel")).isEmpty()))!!(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='welcomeimagepath']".isDisplayed())))
    {
        flag = true;
    }
```

I want the user to login when both the conditions meet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isDisplayed()` is a method of WebElement.

`findElements()` returns a list of WebElements, and `isDisplayed()` can not be called on List. Luckily WebDriver also has method `findElement(By by)` that you can use to get a single WebElement.

Thus your code should look something like this:

```
boolean flag = false;
if (!driver.findElements(By.id("Cancel")).isEmpty() && 
     driver.findElement(By.id("welcomeimagepath")).isDisplayed())
{
    flag = true;
}
```

//edit:

Edited the answer, since it looks like that the search is not path sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your html code you can use below xpath and use the method with return statement then you can call the method in conditional statements so that it will give true or false

```
    public boolean isuserloggedin()
    {
       boolean flag = false;

       if (!driver.findElements(By.id("Cancel)).isEmpty() || driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='WelcomeRefreshButton']")).isDisplayed())
       {
          flag = true;
       }
       return flag;
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are strongly discouraged. Please add some description to your answers explaining what the code does and how it answers the question.

Comment: am new to stack overflow. I will follow from next time thanks